# Coalescing Swift operator for an empty non-nil string

Tags: swift, variable-assignment, string

I have a string variable in Swift:

```
let foo = "bar"
```

But it can also be any other arbitrary string. Now I want to do the following:

```
let bar = ... // either the value of foo, or if foo is "", it will be "default"
```

I looked up "coalescing operator" and it seems it's the right direction. I tried it with the following code:

```
let bar = foo ?? "default"
```

But it seems that when `foo` is empty, it will still take this, and it won't set `default` as the value.

I assume that coalescing operators only work with a `nil` value and not with empty strings. However, is there a solution where I can test my value for being an empty string, and assigning a default value? I can't use if/else, because it will be located in a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference between `""` and `nil`. As is, you are defining foo as "bar", and thus it is non optional so it will never return nil. It sounds like what you need is the ternary operator:

```
let bar = foo.isEmpty ? foo : "default"
```

Also, to expand on return true's answer, you could make an operator that accounts for both optional and empty strings like so:

```
infix operator ???? {}
func ???? (lhs: String?, rhs: String) -> String {
    if let s = lhs {
        if !s.isEmpty {
            return s
        }
    }    
    return rhs
}
```

Comment: Is there a special reason (if you remember ) why you chose to use 4 question marks instead of `return true`'s 3?

Answer (score 7):

Or create your own operator:

```
infix operator ??? {}
func ??? (lhs: String, rhs: String) -> String {
    if lhs.isEmpty {
        return rhs
    }
    return lhs
}
```

And then: `let bar = foo ??? "default"`